# JavaConfig : The type javax.servlet.ServletContext and javax.servlet.ServletException cannot be resolved

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

create my first project in Spring and I have some problem. 
I use JavaConfig to configuration my project and when I start I have this error :

```
Error:(6, 8) java: cannot access javax.servlet.ServletException
class file for javax.servlet.ServletException not found
```

I now I have to add javax.servlet api but I do not know where to do it.
I create my project in IntelliJ Ultimate 2017.

Answer (score 5):

It seems like you haven't included the `javax.servlet.jar` library in your project.

If you're not using any dependency managers, you should add 'javax.servlet.jar' file to your classpath manually with Intellij IDEA: Project Structure (Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S) -> Libraries -> New Project Library -> Java. This jar-file can be downloaded here: http://central.maven.org/maven2/javax/servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.0.1/javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar

If you're using Maven, then just add this dependency to maven pom.xml file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
 </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

ran into a similar problem, I already had a dependency implemented

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

However, the problem was solved by changing the version of

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

to:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.9.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```